# Python Exception Error

Tags: python

I have never done Python programming before but I have done a lot of .NET in C#
There is a need to do some Python and was trying to learn how to throw exceptions in Python.

```
from __future__ import with_statement

import dbi
import timeit
import datetime
import win32com.client
import os
import datetime
import sys
import codecs
import subprocess
import time
import _winreg


def main():
    retCode=0
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print "-----------------------------------------------------"
    print "Start Executing the script", now
    print "-----------------------------------------------------"

    try:
        print "Testing Testing"

    except Exception, err:
        sys.stderr.write('ERROR: %s\n' % str(err))
        retCode=1

    if retCode==1:
        print "======================================"
        print "Errors occured. Please investigate. "
        print "======================================"
    else:
        print "======================================"
        print "No errors found"
        print "======================================"

    print "Retcode:", retCode
    sys.exit(retCode)
main()
```

Does anyobody know why the above code gives me this error ?

```
The error is: 
  File "c:\sample.py", line 28
    retCode=1
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: I don't know the solution, but an improvement over the usage of the `main()` function would be to use `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the indentation at `retCode=1`. If this line has 4 spaces but the line above a tab, it will look the same in your editor but python will complain.

Comment: Thanks. I knew about the 4 spaces for intent. I had though a tab and then 4 spaces. I still don't get the whole concept of spaces in Python :)

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, did you mix tabs and spaces? Make sure each line has the same number of spaces per indentation.